# iAd works but debugger still displays error?

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I have set up a medium rectangle ad on a screen that transitions once the user finishes a game.  Upon loading onto the ad screen, the ad is displayed well and the user presses a button to return to the game.  Once I transition back to that screen again to display the ad, I get the error of:

> 2015-08-24 08:36:48.466 AdPractice[98759:1107031] [AppDeveloper]
>   ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not
>   implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain
>   Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad was unloaded from this
>   banner" UserInfo=0x7fa9315b3270 {ADInternalErrorCode=7,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad was unloaded from this banner,
>   ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain}

However, the banner is displaying as it should, refreshing as it should, and visually it isn't loading and unloading as the error would suggest.  Every 15 second refresh rate I have it displays the success statement.  Code is below(sorry for layout issues, new to posting code)

```
import UIKit
import iAd

class simpleVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var adView: ADBannerView!

    @IBAction func backPush(sender: AnyObject) {

        adView.removeFromSuperview()
        adView.delegate = nil

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("backFromSimple", sender: self)
    }

   func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

        println("success, banner loaded")

        self.view.addSubview(banner)
    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError
        error: NSError!) {
        println("failed to load ad, removed")
        println(error)

        banner.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

The delegate was added by control+dragging the adview from the storyboard onto the view controller.  Someone suggested removing the delegate (which I did) and then releasing it (which I have no idea how to do).

Using XCode 6.4 and Swift 1.2

I read that this could just be a bug and is fine, but I haven't found an answer to remove this strange output.  i don't want the app to get rejected.  Any way to remove this?

Comment: Seems like you are setting you `ADBannerView`'s `delegate` equal to `nil` too soon, `adView.delegate = nil`. Also you have not included the delegate in your class, `class simpleVC: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {`. Why are you removing your `ADBannerView` from your `view` when `backPush` is fired, `adView.removeFromSuperview()`?

Comment: I didn't include it because I thought if it was on my storyboard, and i dragged it to the top and set "delegate" that would have sufficed.  As for removing it, I just thought it made sense to take it off once i wasn't on the screen.  And where do you suggest I set it equal to nil?  That's the last place I can before it transitions to the next screen...